# Angularjs: How to use $resource to serve an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service, angular-resource

I had a $resource that servers two files, names.js and birthday.js:

```
// names.js
{
  name: John,
  name: Mary,
}

// birthday.js
{
  John: 28,
  Mary: 28
}
```

It works great in my controller. But I couldn't run ng-repeat on it. So I converted the data to a format that was used in the [ng-repeat docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat):

```
// friends.js
friends = [{name:'John', age:25}, {name:'Mary', age:28}];
```

But now my provider for friends.js returns an [array of characters](http://i850.photobucket.com/albums/ab64/henthex/data_zps35782516.png) (not very useful) or an [object of characters](http://i850.photobucket.com/albums/ab64/henthex/ScreenShot2013-07-28at62705PM_zps474a8942.png). How can I make it so that my provider returns a useful format of the data?

The query in the service is:

```
friends: $resource('data/friends.js', {}, {
  query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true[or false]}
})
```

In short, how do you use a $resource to provide friends.js?

Answer (score 0):

How do you query your $resource?

The get method is expecting an object while the query method is expecting an array.

This is the default methods available on a $resource :

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

More info available here :

[AngularJS resource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: I've updated my question to include the query. Regardless of setting isArray, the service provides an Object / or Array of characters.
          


I'd like to use this data in the controller, so an object/array of character would be useless for me.

I'd like to keep friends.js as the data because I'd like to run the ng-repeat directive on this dataset.